# Maclaurin series for $(1+x)\cdot e^{-x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I’m having problems with writing Maclaurin series for $$(1+x)\cdot e^{-x}$$ as I need to write it in the form of power series, but I have struggles with using derivatives here.

Comment: If you know the series for $e^x$ , you only have to replace $x$ by $-x$, then truncate at some point and multiply with $x+1$. The result is $$1-1/2x^2+1/3x^3-1/8x^4+O(x^5)$$

Comment: @Peter Yeah, I get it. But how exactly do I transform it into the form of power series?

Comment: Do you mean $(1+x)e^{-x}$?

Comment: @john-doe Yes, sorry.

Comment: @Valerie You mean in the form $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j\cdot x^j$$ with a concrete formula for $a_n$ ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I tried to follow Arthur’s method still it’s hard to find the right power series form for e^(-x)+xe^(-x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $f(x)=(1+x)e^{-x}$. The power series expansion of $e^x$ is $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+x+\frac12 x^2+\frac16x^3+\cdots\\\implies (1+x)e^{-x}=(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^{n}}{(n-1)!}\\=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-n)(-1)^n}{n!}x^n$$
So we have an explicit formula for the coefficient - we can write $(1+x)e^{-x}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j$ with $$a_j=\frac{(1-j)(-1)^j}{j!}$$

---

Equivalently,

$$(1+x)e^{-x}=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-(n+1))(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)n!}x^{n+1}\\=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)(n-1)!}x^{n+1}$$

Comment: But the right formula is: 1+sum(((-1)^n*x^(n+1))/((n+1)(n-1)!)

Comment: Sorry, my keyboard doesn’t seem to work properly. Is it the same with your answer?

Comment: @Valerie see the edit

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Write down the power series for $e^{-x}$. Multiply by $x$ to find the power series of $xe^{-x}$. Finally, take the power series for $e^{-x}$ and the power series for $xe^{-x}$, and add them together, and you have the power series of $e^{-x} + xe^{-x} = (1+x)e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i!}\implies e^{-x}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^ix^i}{i!}$$ so $$(1+x)\cdot e^{-x}=e^{-x}+xe^{-x}=\quad ?$$